# how to check if string matches a specific format with placeholders

Tags: java

String format should be as below. It is a comma seperated and should have two keys **access_token** and **client** and each key should have its value followed by = in format below.

How to write an efficient code to check if the given string matches the below pattern.

access_token=,client=

Comment: If the string has whitespaces after the comma, should it be considered valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `String#matches` here:

```java
String input = "access_token=ABC124,client=blah";
if (input.matches("access_token=.+,client=.+")) {
    System.out.println("VALID");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Pattern`

```
Pattern.matches(regex, match);

Example :


Pattern.matches("access_token=.+,client=.+", "access_token=abcd,client=bdef");
```